# R using apply on data frame to return order and values

Tags: r, apply

My data currently looks like this

```
x          | y          | z
2015-02-12 | 2015-02-03 | 2015-02-06
2015-01-20 | 2015-01-30 | 2015-01-15
```

I need to sort each row from earliest date to oldest. I would like the output to return the indices as well as the values of the sorted order. For example, I'd like to have:

```
1st_index | 2nd_index | 3rd_index | 1st_value  | 2nd_value  | 3rd_value
2         | 3         | 1         | 2015-02-03 | 2015-02-06 | 2015-02-12
3         | 1         | 2         | 2015-01-15 | 2015-01-20 | 2015-01-30
```

I wrote a for loop, but I have so many rows of data that it's too slow. I'd like to use apply, but I'm really struggling.

I would like to do something like the following, but this definitely does not return the intended output.

```
myfunc <- function(x){
  a = order(x, na.last=TRUE)
  y = c(a[1],a[2],a[3],x[a[1]],x[a[2]],x[a[3]])
}

test <- apply(df, 1, function(x) myfunc(x))
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: What exactly not working? Are your columns are of class `Date`? If so, this seems to work `t(apply(df, 1, myfunc))`. You could also make a `data.frame` of it using `as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, myfunc)))`

Comment: This is one of those face palm moments. Just needed to transpose. Thanks so much.

Comment: Btw, you can simplify your function to just `myfunc <- function(x){
  a = order(x, na.last=TRUE);
  y = c(a, x[a])
}`

Comment: Oh that's awesome. Makes it much more robust in case things change in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some data

```
orig = as.data.frame(split(Sys.Date() + runif(12, 100, 200), 1:3))
```

Put the data into 'long' form (`do.call(c, unname(orig))` preserves the class of orig, presumably one of the Date-like classes otherwise order() wouldn't work; important to keep the class of the data throughout, the `apply()` approach does not).

```
df = data.frame(row=as.vector(row(orig)), col=as.vector(col(orig)), 
                value=do.call(c, unname(orig)))
```

Figure out an order based on row and value

```
o = order(df$row, df$value, na.last=TRUE)
df = df[o, , drop=FALSE]
```

and cast the result into your desired output

```
orig[] = split(df$value, seq_along(orig))  # original class / names
cbind(matrix(df$col, ncol=ncol(orig), byrow=TRUE), orig)
```

A `for` loop implementation might be

```
## pre-allocate
result = cbind(matrix(0L, nrow(orig), ncol(orig)), orig)
## fill
cidx = seq_len(ncol(orig))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(result))) {
    o = order(orig[i,], na.last=TRUE)
    result[i, cidx] = o
    result[i, -cidx] = orig[i, o]
}
```

The `for` loop implementation is not likely to be very efficient, because updating rows of a data.frame is very slow; trying to be more efficient here would quickly lead to the 'long data.frame' solution above. The various solutions offered so far are

```
f0 = function(x) {
    as.data.frame(t(apply(x, 1, function(x) {
        o = order(x, na.last=TRUE)
        c(o, x[o])
    })))
}

f1 = function(x) {
    df = data.frame(row=as.vector(row(x)), col=as.vector(col(x)), 
                   value=do.call(c, unname(x)))
    o = order(df$row, df$value, na.last=TRUE)
    df = df[o, , drop=FALSE]
    x[] = split(df$value, seq_along(x))  # original class / names
    cbind(matrix(df$col, ncol=ncol(x), byrow=TRUE), x)
}
```

We know that the solutions diff

```
identical(f0(orig), f1(orig))
## [1] FALSE
```

Here are some timings

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f0(orig), f1(orig), times=5)
## Unit: milliseconds
##     expr       min       lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
## f0(orig) 42.011069 42.12418 42.66665 42.554372 43.034768 43.933247    10
## f1(orig)  2.555936  2.59881  2.70855  2.660635  2.803732  3.017764    10
```

`f1()` seems to be both  closer to correct and faster; maybe it's a little cryptic, and it took some care to make sure date classes were preserved.